# Plot predicted values from lmer longitudinal analysis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lme4, longitudinal

I'm analyzing some longitudinal data using `lme4` package (`lmer function`) with `3 Levels`: measurement points nested in individuals nested in households. I'm interested in linear and non-linear change curves surrounding a specific life event. My model has many time predictors (indicating linear change before and after the event occurs and indicating non-linear change (i.e., squared time variables) before and after the event occurs). Additionally, I have several Level-2 predictors that do not vary with time (i.e., personality traits) and some control variables (e.g., age, gender). So far I did not include any random slopes or cross-level interactions.

This is my model code:

```
model.RI <- lmer(outcome ~ time + female_c + age_c + age_c2 + preLin + preLin.sq + postLin + postLin.sq + per1.c + per2.c + per3.c + per4.c + per5.c + (1 | ID) +  (1 | House))
```

outcome = my dependent variable

`time = year 1, year 2, year 3 ... (until year 9);` this variable symbolizes something like a testing effect

```
female_c = gender centered

age_c = age centered

age_c2 = age squared centered
```

`preLin = time variable` indicating time to the event (this variable is 0 after the event has occurred and is -1 e.g. one year ahead of the event, -2 two years ahead of the event etc.)

```
preLin.sq = squared values of preLin
```

`postLin = time variable` indicating time after the event (this variable is 0 before the event and increases after the event has occurred; e.g. is +1 one year after the event)

```
postLin.sq = squared values of postLin

per1.c until per5.c = personality traits on Level 2 (centered)

ID = indicating the individuum

House = indicating the household
```

I was wondering how I could plot the predicted values of this `lmer` model (e.g., using ggplot2?). I've plotted change curves using the `method=gam` in R. This is a rather data-driven method to inspect the data without pre-defining if the curve is linear or quadratic or whatever. I would now like to check whether my parametric lmer model is comparable to that data-driven `gam-plot` I already have. Do you have any advise how to do this?

I would be more than happy to get some help on this! Please also feel free to ask if I was not precise enough on my explanation of what I would like to do!

Thanks a lot!

[Follow this link: This is how my gam-plot looks like and I hope to get something similar when plotting the predicted values of my lmer model!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpIaO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ggpredict()`-function from the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/). If you want to plot predicted values of time (`preLin`), you would simply write:

```
ggpredict(model.RI, "preLin")
```

The function returns a data frame (see [articles](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/marginaleffects.html)), which you can use in ggplot, but you can also directly plot the results:

```
ggpredict(model.RI, "preLin") %>% plot()
```

or

```
p <- ggpredict(model.RI, "preLin")
plot(p)
```

You could also use the [sjPlot-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/), however, for marginal effects / predicted values, the `sjPlot::plot_model()`-function internally just calls `ggeffects::ggpredict()`, so the results would basically be identical.

Another note to your model: if you have longitudinal data, you should also include your time-variable as random slope. I'm not sure how `postLin` acutally refers to `preLin`, but if `preLin` captures all your measurements, you should at least write your model like this:

```
model.RI <- lmer(
  outcome ~ time + female_c + age_c + age_c2 + preLin + preLin.sq + 
  postLin + postLin.sq + per1.c + per2.c + per3.c + per4.c + per5.c + 
  (1 + preLin | ID) +  (1 + preLin | House)
)
```

If you also assume a quadratic trend for each person (`ID`), you could even add the squared term as random slope.

As your figure example suggests using splines, you could also try this:

```
library(splines)
model.RI <- lmer(
  outcome ~ time + female_c + age_c + age_c2 + bs(preLin) 
  postLin + postLin.sq + per1.c + per2.c + per3.c + per4.c + per5.c + 
  (1 + preLin | ID) +  (1 + preLin | House)
)
p <- ggpredict(model.RI, "preLin")
plot(p)
```

Examples for splines are also demonstrated on the website I mentioned above.

**Edit:**
Another note is related to nesting: you're currently modelling a fully crossed or cross-classified model. If it's completely nested, the random parts would look like this:

```
... + (1 + preLin | House / ID)
```

(see also [this small code-example](https://github.com/strengejacke/brms-snippets/blob/master/nested_fully-crossed_cross-classified_models_in_brms.R)).